# Showing specific content based on drop down selection?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to adapt this code to a project I'm doing. I found it mentioned here.

https://jsfiddle.net/zsL98g01/15/

I need text to populate below based on the selections of both drop down selections. **So if you select House Ware + Camera = It would display a list of cameras**. And this list would only be found with the above 2 selections. I need every combination to be able to provide a text based list.

HTML:

```
    <select name="category1" id="category1">
                    <option value="">Select Category1</option>
                    <option value="home_ware">Home Ware</option>
                    <option value="education">Education</option>
                    <option value="books">Books</option>
                </select>

    <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
                    <option value>Select Category2</option>
                    <!-- Home Ware -->
                    <option rel="home_ware" value="air-conditioners_coolers">Air-Conditioners/Coolers</option>
                    <option rel="home_ware" value="audio-video">Audio/Video</option>
                    <option rel="home_ware" value="beddings">Beddings</option>
                    <option rel="home_ware" value="camera">Camera</option>
                    <option rel="home_ware" value="cell-phones">Cell Phones</option>
                    <!-- Education -->
                    <option rel="Education" value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
                    <option rel="Education" value="Institutes">Institutes</option>
                    <option rel="Education" value="Schools">Schools</option>
                    <option rel="Education" value="Tuitions">Tuitions</option>
                    <option rel="Education" value="Universities">Universities</option>
                    <!-- Books -->
                    <option rel="Books" value="College Books">College Books</option>
                    <option rel="Books" value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                    <option rel="Books" value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
                    <option rel="Books" value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                    <option rel="Books" value="References">References</option>
                </select>
```

JS + jQuery:

```
    $(function(){

var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $("#category2");

$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
});

});
```

CSS:

```
    #category2 option{
    display:none;
    }

    #category2 option.label{
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$subcat.on("change",function(){
    var elemToshow = $cat.val() + '-' + $subcat.val();

  switch(elemToshow) {
    case 'home_ware-camera':
        //Do something
      break;
      case 'education-Colleges':
      //Do something
      break;
      // ...    
  }
```

Honestly i don't think you need to insert rel attribute in your DOM.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know what your comment means, im extremely new to this

Comment: As i see in that part of your code, you have attribute rel for each option. Maybe another part of your code is missing, but on what i see now, you don't need rel attribute, just use option values. DOM Explainations: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp